# WinError 5 access denied after administrator privileges?

Tags: python

I installed a library called stockfish via `pip install stockfish`.

So I went on and tried to setup the Stockfish via:

```
from stockfish import Stockfish

stockfish = Stockfish(r'C:\Users\Acer\Desktop\chess\stockfish-11-win')
```

That throws a WinError 5, access denied:

```
Exception ignored in: <function Stockfish.__del__ at 0x0429AA48>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Acer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\stockfish\models.py", line 270, in __del__
    self.stockfish.kill()
AttributeError: 'Stockfish' object has no attribute 'stockfish'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#4>", line 1, in <module>
    emily = Stockfish(r'C:\Users\Acer\Desktop\chess\stockfish-11-win\src')
  File "C:\Users\Acer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\stockfish\models.py", line 33, in __init__
    self.stockfish = subprocess.Popen(
  File "C:\Users\Acer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\subprocess.py", line 854, in __init__
    self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
  File "C:\Users\Acer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\subprocess.py", line 1307, in _execute_child
    hp, ht, pid, tid = _winapi.CreateProcess(executable, args,
PermissionError: [WinError 5] Zugriff verweigert
```

**What have I done/tried?**
I tried different Stockfish Downloads, running the Idle or CMD as admin, re-installed and used different PCs, but I somehow don't get to work with Stockfish - anyone able to help me out bypassing the access denied? What do I miss when initializing? Trying `Stockfish` returns `<class 'stockfish.models.Stockfish'>` , thus it seems like it's properly imported and functioning.

Comment: do you have write access in `C:\Users\Acer\Desktop\chess\stockfish-11-win` without running as admin??

Comment: @KetZoomer tested it with a .txt file I could access without any problems whatsoever. Besides that Idle / CMD has been run via Admin privileges.